# Populate select drop-down with json

Tags: jquery, json

Using jquery, I am trying to populate a select drop-down with json. I am trying to display a list of countries from the json below...

```
{  
"country":[  
  {  
     "China":[  
        {  
           "tarrifType":"Pay as you go"
        },
        {  
           "fixLine":"23p"
        }
     ],
     "India":[  
        {  
           "sms":"39p"
        },
        {  
           "fixLine":"3p",
           "sms":"59p"
        }
     ],
     "Poland":[  
        {  
           "mobile":"29p",
           "sms":"19p"
        },
        {  
           "tarrifType":"China Pass",
           "fixLine":"23p"
        }
     ]
  }
]
}
```

So far the jquery I have tried to do this with is the following...

```
 $.getJSON("js/widgets/country-picker.json", function(result){
   $.each(result, function(i, field) {
  $('#js-rate-select').append($('<option>').text(field[1]).attr('value',    field[1]));
  });
 });
```

But it does not fill the  select dropdown or give any DOM errors. Any suggestions how I can fix this? I think the issue is because of the json format - which I am able to change Thanks

Comment: Which part of the json do you actually want in the select? The country names or one of the pieces of each country?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json feed returns an array containing only one index, which is an object with the different countries. Therefor, you should say

```
result.country[0].China.tarrifType.
```

And, you would be able to iterate the countries like this:

```
$.each(result.country[0], function(country,data) { console.log(country); }
```

Although, i would recommend to redo your JSON. You could do like this:

```
var result = {
    "country": {
        "China": {
            "tarrifType": "Pay as you go",
            "fixLine": "23p"
        },
        "India": {
            "sms": "39p",
            "fixLine": "3p",
            "sms": "59p"
        },
        "Poland": {
            "mobile": "29p",
            "sms": "19p",
            "tarrifType": "China Pass",
            "fixLine": "23p"
        }
    }
};


$(function () {
    $.each(result.country, function (country, data) {
        console.log("Country : " + country);
        console.log(data); // data.fixLine, data.tarrifType, data.sms

        $('#selectbox').append('<option value="' + country + '">' + country + '</option>');

    });
});
```

jsfiddle here:
[Link to JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3jp36znu/)

Comment: Many thanks for the help and for taking the time to do a fiddle. I also changed the json structure as suggested and its working well. Much appreciated.